# Is there any alternative player "plugin or platform" to run java application instead of java-applet platform?

Tags: java, flash, applet

I'm not good enough in java-programming, But i know its basics. My question is: Is it possible to run java application "java-applet" on explorer without java plugin "i mean java-platform"??

I ask this question -even it's stupid- because i see a lot of people not used java platform "java-plugin" on their explorers. Plus many people advice to not activate that java platform "java-plugin" on explorers. In addition, I think the message of permissions requirement make some people confused about application.

On anther hand, Is it possible to run java application by anther spread plugin such as flash player or anything else?? May be that is wrong question, Playing java by flash player, But i asked that to explain my question.

At the end, Is that possible or not? And if yes, What should i do to get that?

Comment: *"..i see a lot of people not used java platform "java-plugin" on their explorers"*  Some people won't use their explorer.  Me, I prefer Chrome or FireFox.  As to Java, that is what the [deployment toolkit script](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jweb/deployment_advice.html#deplToolkit) is for, to ensure a suitable minimum version is installed before running an applet or offering a link to download the Java Web Start application.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible. You need a Java Virtual machine coupled with the browser to run a java applet.